# How would I change the table header title for each component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently learning React and was doing a project. I got stumped on changing the table header for each table. I tried using different props, but that didn't work.

Here is my code

App.js

```
import React from  "react"
import './App.css';
import FilterableCourseTable from './FilterableCourseTable';

class  App extends React.Component {



  render () {
    console.log("* Inside App")
    return (
        <FilterableCourseTable  />
    );
    
  }
  
}

export default App;
```

FilterableCourseTable.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import InfoBar from "./InfoBar";
import CourseDisplay from "./CourseDisplay";




export default class FilterableCourseTable extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      credits: 0,
      writingCourses : [
        {id: 1, description: "Writing1",semester:'' , prefix:'ENG', number: '368/371', grade: '  '},
        {id: 2, description: "Writing2",semester:'' , prefix:'', number: '  ', grade: '  '},
        {id: 3, description: "Writing3",semester:'' , prefix:'', number: '  ', grade: '  '}
      ],
      speakingCourses : [
        {id: 1, description: "Speaking1", semester:'', prefix: 'SPK', number: '208/230', grade: '  '},
        {id: 2, description: "Speaking2", semester:'', prefix:'', number: '  ', grade: '  '},
        {id: 3, description: "Speaking3", semester:'', prefix:'', number: '  ', grade: '  '},
      ]
    };

    this.handleNameChange = this.handleNameChange.bind(this);
    this.handleCreditChange = this.handleCreditChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleNameChange(studentName) {
    this.setState({
      name: studentName
    });
  }
  
  handleCreditChange(trCredit) {
    this.setState({
      credits: trCredit
    })
  }

  saveData = (collection, item) => {
    console.log("*** Collection: " + collection);
    console.log("*** Item:" + item);
      if (item.id === "") {
          item.id = this.idCounter++;
          this.setState(state => state[collection] 
              = state[collection].concat(item));
      } else {
          this.setState(state => state[collection] 
              = state[collection].map(stored => 
                    stored.id === item.id ? item: stored))
                    
      } 
  }

  deleteData = (collection, item) => {
    this.setState(state => state[collection] 
        = state[collection].filter(stored => stored.id !== item.id));
}


  render() {
    console.log("** --- FilterableCourseTable ---");
    return (
      <div>
        <InfoBar
          name={this.state.name}
          credit={this.state.credits}
          onNameChange={this.handleNameChange}
          onCreditChange={this.handleCreditChange}
        />
        <CourseDisplay  
                    name={this.state.name}
                    credit={this.state.credits}
                    courses={ this.state.writingCourses }
                    saveCallback={ c => this.saveData("writingCourses", c) }
                    deleteCallback={ c => this.deleteData("writingCourses", c) } 
        />
        <CourseDisplay  
                    name={this.state.name}
                    credit={this.state.credits}
                    courses={ this.state.speakingCourses }
                    saveCallback={ c => this.saveData("speakingCourses", c) }
                    deleteCallback={ c => this.deleteData("speakingCourses", c) } 
        />

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

CourseTable.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import CourseRow from "./CourseRow";
[enter image description here][1]

export  class CourseTable extends Component {
  
  render() {
    const name = this.props.name;
    const credit = this.props.credit;
    
    const courses = this.props.courses;



    
    

    const rows = [];
    console.log("--- CourseTable ---");
    console.log ("Name:" + name);
    console.log ("Credit:" + credit);
    courses.forEach((c) => {
      console.log("Received a course: " + c.id + " "+ c.prefix + " "+ c.number);

      
      
      if (c.id === 1) {
        console.log("--course 1 " + c.course);
        rows.push(
          <CourseRow
            course={c}
            key={c.id} 
            editCallback= { this.props.editCallback }
          />
        );
      }
      if (c.id === 2 && credit < 71) {
        console.log("--course 2 " + c.course);
        rows.push(
          <CourseRow
            course={c}
            key={c.id}
            editCallback= { this.props.editCallback }
          />
        );
      }
      if (c.id === 3 && credit < 41) {
        console.log("--course 3 " + c.course);
        rows.push(
          <CourseRow
            course={c}
            key={c.id}
            editCallback= { this.props.editCallback }
          />
        );
      }
        
    });
   
    console.log(`{name}`);
    return (
      <><table className="table table-sm table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th colSpan="7" className="bg-primary text-white text-center h4 p-2">
                for {this.props.name}
            </th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Semester</th>
            <th>Prefix</th>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Grade</th>
            <th>Editing</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
      </table>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

I provided a picture of what I currently have I want to add a new title right before "for" for each table. i.e. Writing for table 1 and Speaking for table 2.

Here is what I currently have.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/63Ux8.png

Answer (score 0):

You could render `title` property inside the `CourseTable` component:

```
<th colSpan="7" className="bg-primary text-white text-center h4 p-2">
  {this.props.title} for {this.props.name}
</th>
```

And use it like this:

```
<CourseTable
  title="Writing"
  name={this.state.name}
  credit={this.state.credits}
  courses={ this.state.writingCourses }
  saveCallback={ c => this.saveData("writingCourses", c) }
  deleteCallback={ c => this.deleteData("writingCourses", c) }

<CourseTable
  title="Speaking"
  name={this.state.name}
  credit={this.state.credits}
  courses={ this.state.speakingCourses }
  saveCallback={ c => this.saveData("speakingCourses", c) }
  deleteCallback={ c => this.deleteData("speakingCourses", c) } 
/>
```

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I got it. I had to call the CourseDisplay component element again and delete a CourseTable component element. Thank you!